# how to trigger intentionally to rebuild initramfs and vmlinuz

Tags: initramfs

I was learning to use debootstrap and forgot to include some modules when initramfs was rebuild. Later I copied over what was missing, but the missed files were not included when the system was rebooted - only after some more additions (with apt install), which triggered the initramfs rebuild, the problem was fixed.

I would have liked to trigger or force to rebuild initramfs and vmlinuz but could not find a way (my understanding of the boot process is still incomplete; thank you for enlightment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need some modules in the initramfs, list them in the file */etc/initramfs-tools/modules*.

To trigger a rebuild of the initramfs, you would call `update-initramfs` which itself calls `mkinitramfs`. Both programs have man pages that can help you further.

Comment: thank you - I assumed there was an simple command, but I could not find it. I still have much to learn to use debootstrap effectively.